# how to have global variables among different modules in Python

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

I investigated that scope of global variables in python is limited to the module. But I need the scope to be global among different modules. Is there such a thing? I played around `__builtin__` but no luck.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access global variables from other modules by importing them explicitly.

In module `foo`:

```
  joe = 5
```

In module `bar`:

```
  from foo import joe
  print joe
```

Note that this isn't recommended, though. It's much better to hide access to a module's variables by using functions.

Comment: It's even better not to store mutable state in global variables at all, but rather to use classes.

Comment: @Eli Bendersky, what do you mean by "It's much better to hide access to a module's variables by using functions"? @ Mike Graham, what do you mean by "use classes"? How do you do that to get what he wants?

Comment: @LWZ: What I meant is that when a module lets other modules directly access its data, it may lead to hard-to-debug problems. If access to global data is absolutely required for some reason, at least get/set functions should be provided. These functions make it much easier to modify the code later (say, replace the global data by something else) and debug it if problems arise.

Answer (score 3):

Python does not support globals shared between several modules: *this is a feature*. Code that implicitly modifies variables used far away is confusing and unmaintainable. The *real* solution is to encapsulate all state within a class and pass its instance to anything that has to modify it. This can make code clearer, more maintainable, more testable, more modular, and more expendable.

Answer (score 0):

Scopes beyond the local must be written to via a reference to the scope, or after a `global` or `nonlocal` (3.x+) directive.